# PhoneGap Android - Adding users to test the app

Tags: android, cordova

So I just uploaded my APK to PhoneGap. Now I've done this with iOS before and I had to create a provisioning profile (through Apple Developer site) with each phone ID for the users to download the app. Now Android is a different thing, I have NO CLUE how to add the users to test the app. It's in the "Permissions" tab. I've searched and have found ZERO information about this. It has to be something so simple that I am missing :/

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do anything for Android - you can send the final APK file to any testers and they can install it directly on their phones.

Note: they may need to turn on 'Install from unknown sources' - if they do not have that enabled the system will prompt them to turn it on when they try to install it

Comment: Oh LOL. I guess it's actually simpler than iOS. I'll give it a shot. I opened the link of the final APK from PhoneGap on my computer just to see what it said and it said "Build MIA. You do not have permission to install this build." That's what got me initially confused.